# Issues installing cudnn and cudatoolkit

Tags: python, tensorflow, cuda

I am trying to use tensorflow with GPU. My current cuda version is as follows:

```
nvcc -V
    
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2022 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Tue_Mar__8_18:36:24_Pacific_Standard_Time_2022
Cuda compilation tools, release 11.6, V11.6.124
Build cuda_11.6.r11.6/compiler.31057947_0
```

When I attempt to use the following for installation:

```
conda install cudnn=8.7.0=cuda11.6_0
```

I receive back the following error:

```
PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - cudnn==8.7.0=cuda11.6_0
```

I attempted to google around to find an answer, but cannot find anything that works. One solution stated to use `!conda search cudnn` to list compatible versions, but when I do this I do not see my installed version of cuda (11.6)... I receive the following list:

```
    Loading channels: ...working... done
# Name                       Version           Build  Channel             
cudnn                          7.1.4       cuda8.0_0  pkgs/main           
cudnn                          7.1.4       cuda9.0_0  pkgs/main           
cudnn                          7.3.1      cuda10.0_0  pkgs/main           
cudnn                          7.3.1       cuda9.0_0  pkgs/main           
cudnn                          7.6.0      cuda10.0_0  pkgs/main           
cudnn                          7.6.0      cuda10.1_0  pkgs/main           
cudnn                          7.6.0       cuda9.0_0  pkgs/main      
cudnn                          7.6.4      cuda10.0_0  pkgs/main           
cudnn                          7.6.4      cuda10.1_0  pkgs/main           
cudnn                          7.6.4       cuda9.0_0  pkgs/main           
cudnn                          7.6.5      cuda10.0_0  pkgs/main           
cudnn                          7.6.5      cuda10.1_0  pkgs/main           
cudnn                          7.6.5      cuda10.2_0  pkgs/main           
cudnn                          7.6.5       cuda9.0_0  pkgs/main           
cudnn                          7.6.5       cuda9.2_0  pkgs/main           
cudnn                          8.2.1      cuda11.3_0  pkgs/main
```

Does anyone have a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

You can't install cuDNN 8.7.0 via `conda` as you can check by `!conda search cudnn`!

Download it directly from the [NVIDIA](https://developer.nvidia.com/rdp/cudnn-download) website. Then follow the [installation guide](https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/sdk/cudnn-install/index.html) to install the library.